# DES Bitslice SBox How compute the 4 output variables

Tags: des

I am not understanding how to compute the output bits of a 6-to-4-SBOX with bitslice technique in DES. Matthew Kwan made a brief recap in his paper "Reducing the Gate Count of Bitslice DES" of Biham original paper. He wrote:

> Basically, for each S-box, the technique is to take two of the input
> bits, expand them to all 16 possible functions of two variables, and
> use the remaining four S-box inputs to select from those 16 functions.
> However, the details are slightly more complicated

I believe that I understand how to expand 2 variables to 16 functions (from f0 till f15)... But how do I select now with my remaining 4 Input Bits all 4 Outputs?

The paper of Matthew Kwan can be found here: http://fgrieu.free.fr/Mattew%20Kwan%20-%20Reducing%20the%20Gate%20Count%20of%20Bitslice%20DES.pdf

Comment: I'd suggest you look at the original paper that this one just summarizes, but I assume that there's some fixed lookup table (again encoded in gates) for each of the 4 output bits that maps the remaining 4 input bits to an index into f0..f15. How those look specifically depends on the concrete S-box in question.

Comment: It isn't clear this is a programming question. Also see your identical question on [Cryptography Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/98757/des-sbox-output-with-bitslice) which has an accepted answer.